# Tags: Dry-Hop & Dry-Hopping

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Suggested removal, we seem to have duplicate tags for "Dry-Hop" & "Dry-Hopping".

Side note we seem to have duplicate tags in the Meta "tags" and "tagging"

Comment: Over 2 weeks later and no votes. So no-one's listening or no-one cares! :)

Comment: Well +1 so more people agree than disagree, lol.
+2 if you account that I can't vote it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makes sense to me to merge them - I'll leave it a few days and wait for any opinions from the community before merging.

Community: Please vote the question up if you agree with the merge, or down if you don't.

Comment: It's been three months, and the post has upvotes and no negative comments. Let's do it!

Comment: Sure, it was following protocol - trying to get some feedback before just plodding on with it! I'll merge them now.